Program icon in taskbar is text document icon rather than icon appearing on desktop
I have a .Net 4.7.2 WinForms project build using VS 2022. The application icon property is set to a custom icon which appears on the desktop as a shortcut . The icon is a multi-resolution file created online at https://redketchup.io/icon-converter. This icon is used as the form icon for the 1st form displayed. However, the icon which appears in the taskbar is the one used for a shortcut to a text file as follows .  The icon appearing in the list of programs shown by control panel is also not the custom icon. . Applications from other projects have the correct custom icon appearing in the task bar and the Programs list. How can I make the custom icon appear in the taskbar and program list?

The problem was the wrong icon was stored in the icon cache. Following the procedure at https://www.elevenforum.com/t/rebuild-icon-cache-in-windows-11.2049/ to clear the cache allowed the correct icon to show in the taskbar but the custom icon does not appear in the programs listing from Control Panel.
